# Row_number() Partition by - For Repeated Values

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for the new post. I dont know how specifically search for the my requirement.

Here is the scenario,

```
          **Location Name      Datetime**
          ABC                  2014-05-01 09:15
          ABC                  2014-05-01 09:25
          XYZ                  2014-05-01 09:35
          PQR                  2014-05-01 09:45
          ABC                  2014-05-01 09:55
```

These are the data's im having, I need the result as below,

```
          **Location Name      Datetime**      Row Number
          ABC                  2014-05-01 09:15     1
          ABC                  2014-05-01 09:25     1
          XYZ                  2014-05-01 09:35     2
          PQR                  2014-05-01 09:45     3
          ABC                  2014-05-01 09:55     4
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Could you explain your numbering a bit? Same location name twice in order gives the same row number?

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Is your requirement is that if location name is same back to back then you want to give them same row number ?

Comment: I need a unique number for every location based on the datetime, If I apply partition by location it will group all the location then give the row number. I need if new location comes in between it should not group

Comment: Probably you should share your current SQL code that you're using?

Comment: I am using it for vehicle GPS Traking, having gps location. A vehicle may come to same location multiple times I need a sequence of travel. SKY : i have tried below code but it didnt works.  "select location,
  rn = row_number() over(partition by location order by gpsdatetime)
from Table_Temp"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012 or newer, you could for example use [`LAG() OVER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to compare a row with the previous one. That allows you to count only differences from the last row (here generating 0 or 1 depending on whether there is a difference or not);

If you then use `SUM() OVER()` to add up the differences, you'll get what you want;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [Location Name], [Datetime], 
         CASE WHEN LAG([Location Name]) 
                   OVER (ORDER BY [Datetime]) <> [Location Name] 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END rn
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT [Location Name], [Datetime],
       1 + SUM(rn) OVER (ORDER BY [Datetime]) [Row Number]
FROM cte
ORDER BY [Datetime];
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35a85/1).

Comment: Straight up awesome!